# How to use the schedule trigger in YAML with on-premise Azure DevOps 2019?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

Here is my yaml:

```
schedules:
- cron: "*/10 * * * *"
  displayName: Every 10 minutes every day
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

steps:
- powershell: .\Scan.ps1
  displayName: Scan Builds
  name: ScanBuilds
```

And here is what I get during the build:

[image]

When I remove the `schedules` section from the yaml leaving just the `steps` section - the build works (without schedules, of course).

We are using self hosted agents.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No any YAML syntax wrong on your script. Just because until now, for Azure Devops Server or TFS, YAML scheduled trigger does not supported for them.

[image]

See this doc: [Azure Devops server Scheduled trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=schema#scheduled-trigger)

To use scheduled trigger, for Azure Devops server users, the only method is using Classic editor type.